# thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x94cabb20)

Tags: android

hellow

i am trying to integrate the payment gateway of stripe and i am getting this error.

My Menifest file is as below:

```
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.saubhagyam.paymentstripeintegration">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
        android:value="true" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and my logcat is:

> 05-03 18:08:45.184 3425-3425/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
>
> 05-03 18:08:45.264 3425-3425/com.example.saubhagyam.paymentstripeintegration D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> 05-03 18:08:45.264 3425-3425/com.example.saubhagyam.paymentstripeintegration W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x94cabb20)
>
> 05-03 18:13:45.394 3425-3425/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3425 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the whole way of implementing by integrating the stripe input method so it is giving me the inbuilt functionality and i cna use it sucessfully.

Thanks.